# SE chat destroys ASCII art

Tags: support, chat

Sometimes I like to post an image of myself in the [Travel SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) chatroom. Normally, I use ASCII art for this, which should look like the following:

```
  ROFL:ROFL:LOL:ROFL:ROFL
       ______|_____
 L    /           
LOL===            []
 L    ______________
         |     |
       -------------/
```

However, if I post this in the chatroom, it seems that all whitespaces are trimmed. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Nice picture. O.o

Comment: Oh, my imagination is failing me badly. I needed gnostradamus' answer to recognize a helicopter above!

Comment: Do you want to say that I'm ugly?

Comment: No, @Roflcoptr, I wouldn't say that *not* looking like a helicopter qualifies as ugly! ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Works for me:

[image: phew phew!]

Make sure to click on `fixed font`

Comment: Thanks for the help here and directly in the chat. Now it works like a charm!

Comment: @Roflcoptr no problemo ^_^

Comment: I don't see any "fixed font" button. Do I need to enter more than a line of text in the text box? I tried entering a single line, but I didn't see any button being added, and I see just two buttons ("send" and "upload…").

Comment: @kiamlaluno lol wow. 2 years on SO and never been on chat? :-P (you need multiple lines)

Comment: If you mean _Stack Overflow_ chat, then I have never been there. I have been in the chat room for _Drupal Answers_, EL&U, and _Meta Stack Overflow_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno all the same API :-P

Answer (score 23):

You call that a ROFLCOPTER? For shame!

[image]

Comment: yes, yes, very funny but does not answer the OP at all...

Comment: Sweet... So were you just waiting for the right moment to post this?

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama: I know, but a comment just didn't seem to do it justice.

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama Since when do answers have to _actually_ answer the question on meta?

Comment: @gnostradamus ahhh!! i think its giving me a seizure! (blinking out of control!!!)

Comment: @yoda in my experience -- most of the time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sadly, I can't take credit. It was a Google image search. [Here's the site I got it from.](http://www.sandelman.ottawa.on.ca/People/Justin_Hornosty/ROFL/)

Comment: If you don't mind, I fixed the animation so it doesn't do that annoying flashing.

Comment: I like the [Battlefield3 version](http://s3.amazonaws.com/kym-assets/photos/images/list/000/000/522/Roflcopter.gif) better.